# Switch from Windows to Mac OS using Boot Camp

Tags: macos, boot-camp

I am using MBP 2015 running OS  Catalina.
I installed second partition Windows 10 using Boot Camp.
The issue I have on Windows: I want to reboot into Mac not by holding Alt key but by using icon.
On Task Bar I select icon Boot Camp, click on item 'Restart in OS X...'
It pops up a message: 'Are you sure you want ... Your computer will start up using OS X..'
I click OK and got error message: 'Could not locate OS boot volume'
How could I fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Boot Camp Windows support software. The latest versions can now read APFS.
You need to start this from the Mac side & need a spare 16GB USB stick.

Format MS-DOS/MBR
From Boot Camp Assistant, Download Windows support software
Save the download to the USB
Reboot in Windows - Install.

Comprehensive instructions at Apple - https://support.apple.com/HT204923

Comment: thanks for advice. I am planning to follow it. The only concern is: will it require to reinstall Windows OS or only fix boot camp issue?

Comment: It requires nothing except as mentioned - updating the Windows support software

Comment: That’s great. Thanks again. The only concern left is that my hard drive is 120 Gb and ~60 Gb were available. During boot camp install process it allocated 37 Gb for Windows and did not give me the option to resize. Hence I have Windows 10 running on 37 Gb partition with ~13 Gb available. For now it runs fine. My question: could I leave it 'as is'? Thanks

Comment: Apple provides no method to resize Boot Camp partitions after initial creation other than completely erase & start again from scratch. At initial creation if it will not let you change size, it's because it has deemed you don't have enough space to do anything else… so, yes, leave it as it is.

Comment: Thanks so much. Highly appreciate your responses

Comment: @Tetsuin - I followed Apple instructions and installed Windows support software successfully. Unfortunately it did not make any difference. Widows still does not recognize OS X. msconfig-boot also does not see Mac. Hence from Mac I have a workaround to set OS from Startup Disk app but from Windows OS I don't have an option to boot into Mac. Well ... not convenient. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any other way to achieve it from within Windows. Personally, as I rarely use Boot Camp, I just swap at boot by holding Opt. I've never tried updating my Windows control panel to see if it works, or if it needs a specific version of BCA etc. Make sure you do have the latest BCA on the Mac side.